# Learning Javascript/Jquery promise&deferred, issue with $.when multiple use

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

```
    //just a function to simulate, ajax etc.
    function wait () {

        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        console.log('hello')setTimeout(deferred.resolve,3000);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    var func = function () {

        var first,before,after,resolvePromise,main;
        var beforeList = [];
        var afterList = [];
        var def = new $.Deferred();

        //push to array function
        first = function () {

            beforeList.push(wait);  
            beforeList.push(wait);
            afterList.push(wait);
            console.log('first done', beforeList,afterList)
        }

        //this must run before the main
        before = function () {

            var beforeDef = new $.Deferred();

            $.when.apply($,beforeList).done(function () {
                console.log('before', new Date().getTime())
                beforeDef.resolve();
            });

            return beforeDef.promise();
        }

        //this must run after main
        after = function () {

            var afterDef = new $.Deferred();

            $.when.apply($,afterList).done(function () {
                console.log('after', new Date().getTime())
                afterDef.resolve();
            });

            return afterDef.promise();
        }

        // this is main function
        main = function () {
            console.log('doing job in main function', new Date().getTime())
        }

        //handler
        resolvePromise = function () {
            def.resolve();
            return def.promise();
        }

        //action
        var step = def.then(first);
        var step1 = step.then(before);
        var step2 = step1.then(main);
        var step3 = step2.then(after)
        .done(function () {
            console.log('all done')
        });
        resolvePromise();
    }
func();
```

I am just starting to learn promise&deferred. Here is my code. My main goal is, 'creating two arrays full of function'. Which name is afterList and beforeList. I want to run those before and after my main function.

My main issue is i can't make work the lists in $.when().

Comment: Other than this looking overly complex, i don't see anything wrong with the way you're using $.when and then.

Comment: And it seems to run in the correct order: http://jsfiddle.net/pRKt6/

Comment: Yes, order is right but it suppose to say 'hello' at console :) 2 times for before, 1 time for after.

Comment: Ah, well you're never executing the wait method. :p

Comment: I thought when method will do it. Am i wrong ? :) Teach me master!

Comment: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Gsn7/4/ however, as you see, that's not actually how you want it to work, you want the wait for after to not start until the wait for before is complete. Sadly there's no way around that without breaking down your step process. http://jsfiddle.net/2Gsn7/6/

Comment: the when method does not execute functions, it just binds to their done callbacks if they exist.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help,  i will be better at this soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list that is passed to `$.when` needs to be one of promises, not one of functions that will yield them when called. You need to trigger the `wait`s yourself:

```
function first() {
    beforeList.push(wait());  
    beforeList.push(wait());
    afterList.push(wait());
    console.log('first done', beforeList,afterList)
}
```

Also, I wouldn't rely on that global variables `beforeList`/`afterList`. You should construct the list (and start the tasks) and apply the `$.when` in one single step.

And don't construct Deferreds so often (`def`, `beforeDef`, `afterDef`). The main advantage of promises is their chainability, you should not need to resolve any of them manually. Too easily you forget to handle errors and pass them on, which is automated if you simply reuse the promises or call `then` to pipe functions.

```
function before() {
    var beforeList = [];
    beforeList.push(wait());
    beforeList.push(wait());

    var beforeProm = $.when.apply($, beforeList);
    beforeProm.done(function () {
        console.log('before', new Date().getTime())
    });
    return beforeProm;
}
// same thing, coded simpler:
function after() {
    var afterList = [ wait() ];

    return $.when.apply($, afterList).done(function () {
        console.log('after', new Date().getTime())
    });
}

function main() {
    console.log('doing job in main function', new Date().getTime())
    return undefined; // the results of the main job which
                      // after needs to wait for
}

// action - without an extra "handler"
before().then(main).then(after).done(function () {
    console.log('all done')
});
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I am working for better JS and this answer is stimulating.